# VB.net catch control that raises event

Tags: vb.net, events, dynamic, textbox

I'm currently creating a formthat dynamically adds controls inclusive textbox controls. could be 1 or 100 I don't know from the start.

When the textbox is created I add a Event on the textbox.

```
AddHandler Textbox1.TextChanged, AddressOf SET_DIAMETER
```

And created a sub that should do something with the event.

```
Private Sub SET_DIAMETER(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print("Textbox1.textchanged event.")

End Sub
```

The event is raised when the text is changed and my `debug.print()` is executed.

But now I would like to know what textbox is raising the event so I can process the newly entered value properly.

How would you do this?

Comment: `sender` == the event sender

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the sender as a textbox and do what you want.

Something like that:

```
Private Sub SET_DIAMETER(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   Dim TextBox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

   Debug.Print(TextBox.Name & ".textchanged event.")

End Sub
```